# Odoo default database for all user

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have three database (public, test, test1) is it possible for all user after open my URL redirect to public database without choose database from list?

Database (test, test1) only admin can see.

Comment: Add this one line to you config file : dbfilter = public

Comment: @VikiChavada Tnx for help, can you help me where is location config file?

Comment: Which version of odoo you are using?

Comment: You cannot do this without editing the template of the login page because when you select the database you didn't loggin at all.  How would you know the user if you don't know i think you should edit the template to matche your needs

Comment: @VikiChavada  odoo9

Comment: @CherifOdoo You are right. one other solution is that we can create two different config file one for admin user to run odoo and other config for other users with different port and user.

Comment: @VikiChavada What is finally decision for odoo 9?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

The list of database shown to select belongs to the postgres user that you use to connect odoo to postgres.

You can create two postgres user (public_user, test_user) :
 for public database make the owner public_user.
 for test, test1 make the owner test_user.

run two instance of odoo the first one connect to postgres using public_user and here you can select only one database(public).

the other one use test_user to connect to postgres so you can select only 2 database (test,test1).

Answer (score 0):

When you run server you need to mention your default database name followed by *--db-filter*

Ex: **`--db-filter database_name`**

```
 ./odoo-server --addons-path=addons/ --db_user=openerp  --db_password=openerp --db-filter=jbe_gs
```

Comment: Where is location for odoo 9 version?

Comment: You should run this form the odoo 9 directory. For example i have my odoo Instance in this path: odoo@odoo:/opt/gsj_jb_10$